# iOS: Reuse the TabBarController with removing some tabs of the old controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with 5 items. I need to reuse this tab view in another place with removing some items. How can I do that. There is only isEnabled button for programmatically doing that. But I need to hide the tab items.

Case 1: Need to display all the tab items from storyboard

```
@IBAction func partialAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let  partialTabController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as! MainTabController
    partialTabController.selectedViewController = partialTabController.viewControllers?[3]

    present(partialTabController,animated: true,completion: nil)

}
```

Case 2: Display only a few of the tabs in another section of the application

```
@IBAction func partialAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let  partialTabController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as! MainTabController
    partialTabController.selectedViewController = partialTabController.viewControllers?[3]

    // Can I remove some of the tab item using code here

    present(partialTabController,animated: true,completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Hi @Krishnakumar CN it would help if you'd add a snippet of your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

for Objective c
For set different tab bars on different screen by single TabBarController... 
Create the extension class for UITabBarController and create the custom function  bar

```
   -(void)customTabBar {
[self.tabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];  //[CommonFunctions colorWithRed:255.0 green:240.0 blue:237.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[item0 setTitle:@"Home"];
[item0 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item0 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Homeblue"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

[item1 setTitle:@"Browse"];
[item1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item1 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browseblue"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

[item2 setTitle:@"Post"];
[item2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Post"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item2 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Postblue"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item3 setTitle:@"Activity"];
[item3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activity"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item3 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activityblue"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item4 setTitle:@"Profile"];
[item4 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[item4 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profileblue"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];


[item0 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, -3, 0)];
[item1 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, -3, 0)];
[item2 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, -3, 0)];
[item3 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, -3, 0)];
[item4 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, -3, 0)];
```

}

Now you can create the class instance and use tab according to you ....

And create the instance of your class in appdelegate and create function for add tabs according to you

Create instance for extension class

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) CustomTabBarViewController *tabBarController;


  -(void)createTabBarContoller
{
  //Created all tabs controller to be the default for tabs
  UIViewController *viewController1 = [[HomeViewController alloc] 
  initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

  UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SaleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SaleViewController" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

  UIViewController *viewController3 = [[SellCameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SellCameraViewController" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

  UIViewController *viewController4 = [[ActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];

  UIViewController *viewController5 = [[MeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeViewController" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navController5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController5];

  self.tabBarController = [[CustomTabBarViewController alloc] init];
  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4, navController5];

  [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
  [self.tabBarController customTabBar];
  self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50;
  self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255.0 green:236.0/255.0 blue:236.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
  self.tabBarController.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true;

  [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
}
```

Actually i am using it swift also but right now i don't have swift code ...